# Any drawback if CKRecordID.recordName is generated on client?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckrecord

It could provide a more smooth user experience if `recordName` is generated on client.

```
var uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

Do you know any disadvantage to do it?

Comment: Good Idea! Does that work? This could indeed speed up some situations.

Comment: it works, sometimes it can speed somewhat up things, i.e. if I want to show content just if all fields on client was populated, also appropriate field for `recordName` then don't need to wait for approval form server

Comment: How did you do this? I tried setting the record.RecordID but that one is readonly. When I try to set record.setValue(recordId.recordName, forKey: "RecordID") I get the error that RecordID is a reserved keyword

Comment: Ah, sorry, found it. It's in the constructor:  CKRecord(recordType: <#String!#>, recordID: <#CKRecordID!#>)

Comment: Briliant... You deserve a couple of hundred points for this suggestion. Creating a RecordID like this is now the default behavior of EVCloudKitDao. Ik makes the demo app more responsive.

Comment: thanks, by the way, do you know / have any apps in App Store, that already uses `CloudKit`? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/ios-apps-using-cloudkit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`recordName` is always generated on the client.

If no `recordName` is supplied by your application the CloudKit framework will generate a UUID on the client side before sending it to the server.

There is no speedup in generating a UUID in your own code versus letting the CloudKit framework generate one for you.

Client-created `recordName`s exist to help your application map CloudKit records to your own local data storage. If you don't need to do that then you can leave it up to CloudKit.

Comment: since a save action is an async operation, you will be able to know the id before the callback returns. So you could save and forget and still use the ID. Also you could predefine multiple objects with a relation to each other without first saving them.

Comment: Thanks- you're right. I was focusing on performance over the network. Defining your own recordName would let you know what the ID was before the save completed.

Comment: The exception, if you could call it that, is when you don't 'own' the record - namely, I'm thinking of `CKUserIdentity.userRecordID`, which represents an iCloud account holder, and is not generated by you. If your schema is built around UUIDs (which must be in 8-4-4-12 format if constructing from a `uuidString`), then this can throw you for a loop [I speak from harsh experience.]

Answer (score 1):

That should be exactly the designed purpose of the given `CKRecordID` constructors.

As long as you don't try to insert the same generated ID into multiple records (which might force you to add a little more error handling), I can't see any disadvantages here.